# How to undo typing (not command output) in iPython shell

Tags: shell, ipython, undo

Is there a keyboard command for undoing typing in iPython? Note: I am *not* talking about undoing the result of a command you've executed.

Suppose I copied and pasted a few variable names as arguments into a long function call, and then realized they are the wrong arguments. Can I do an equivalent of ctrl-z or something that undoes the paste operation?

Ctrl-z kills the iPython session, so not recommended.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl-_</kbd> (underscore) or <kbd>Ctrl-x</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-u</kbd>

If you deleted something with <kbd>ctrl-w</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl-k</kbd> and so on
you can just paste it back with <kbd>ctrl-y</kbd>.

See `readline(1)` for additional hotkeys.

Comment: Very good, thanks for the reference. Ctrl-u is also a lifesaver because it clears the line, which is really helpful when you use the up arrow to scroll back through history and end up stuck with very long commands.

Comment: By the way, to undo the entire line you can press `esc-r`

Comment: I cant find how to redo... i seached "redo" in bash manual using `man bash | grep redo` but found nothing. Does anybody know how to REDO ?

Comment: @ashuvssut: It is not possible, as far as I know

Answer (score 5):

IPython uses the GNU readline library.  The [standard shortcut for "undo"](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html#SEC21) is Ctrl-_, but this might not undo a full paste operation with one press.  A paste operation in a (Linux) terminal is done by simulating user input, so readline will see many keystrokes, not just one.  You might need to press the chortcut several times.